# How to index an property object in MongoDB?

Tags: index, mongodb

I've the following sample document:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("556e177ca43da29e040041a7"),
    "user_id" : NumberLong(24),
    "request_datetime" : ISODate("2015-06-02T15:52:12.000-05:00"),
    "total_amount" : 102.62,
    "status" : NumberLong(1),
    "adfields" : {
        "27" : "413703562015060200132",
        "28" : "S003POS4",
        "29" : "HAYLEYS",
        "30" : "1"
    }
}
```

The problem is that i need to index the **"adfields"** property, but it doesn't work with a "multikey" index type, neither using "single field index".
I tried to index the **adfields** property using a single field index, but when i make a query for an specific value of **adfields.27** it doesn't use the index.
I can't make an single field index for **adfields.27** because those numbers are created dynamically.

Do you have any idea of how to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What kind of queries you want to optimize?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make this work after altering your model. Hopefully this still fulfills the use case you are targeting. To bypass the dynamic nature of your fields, I created a field named "field" and a field named "value". This allows me to create a multikey index on known fields.

```
db.myColl.insert(
{

"user_id" : NumberLong(24),
"request_datetime" : ISODate("2015-06-02T15:52:12.000-05:00"),
"total_amount" : 102.62,
"status" : NumberLong(1),
"adfields" : [
    {field:"27", value : "413703562015060200132"},
    {field:"28", value: "S003POS4"},
    {field:"29", value: "HAYLEYS"},
    {field:"30", value: "1"}
    ]

})
```

Then I executed a find against this for db.myColl.find({"adfield.field":"30"}) for a before picture of the query. I also used db.myColl.explain().find() to analyze it.

Then I created the index via     db.myColl.createIndex({"adfield.field"1,"adfield.value":1"}).

I executed the find from above and sure enough I see an IXScan and isMultiKey is true in the explain() output.

Again; hopefully the alteration to your model still keeps with the spirit of what you are attempting to accomplish.

You can read more details about mutlikey via http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/ .

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that i need to index the "adfields" property, but it
>   doesn't work with a "multikey" index type, neither using "single field
>   index". I tried to index the adfields property using a single field
>   index, but when i make a query for an specific value of adfields.27.

I am sure here you are doing some mistake because adfields is array of object and 27 is inside the one document value of array.

As MongoDB documented [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-properties/) for Index Properties. If you want to create a index for particular 27 documents field then you should use a partial index. Because a partial index indexes only documents that meet specified filter criteria.

As per **MongoDB BOL** [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/) Partial indexes only index the documents in a collection that meet a specified filter expression. By indexing a subset of the documents in a collection, partial indexes have lower storage requirements and reduced performance costs for index creation and maintenance.

To create a partial index, use the [db.collection.createIndex()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/#db.collection.createIndex) method with the `partialFilterExpression` option. The `partialFilterExpression` option accepts a document that specifies the filter condition using:

1. equality expressions (i.e. field: value or using the  [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/#op._S_eq) operator),
2. [`$exists: true`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists) expression,
3. [`$gt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/#op._S_gt),  [`$gte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/#op._S_gte),  [`$lt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/#op._S_lt),  [`$lte`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/#op._S_lte) expressions,
4. [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#op._S_type) expressions,
5. [`$and`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operator at the top-level only

For Example

**Create a Partial Index On A Collection**

Consider a collection restaurants containing documents that resemble the following

```
{
   "_id" : ObjectId("5641f6a7522545bc535b5dc9"),
   "address" : {
      "building" : "1007",
      "coord" : [
         -73.856077,
         40.848447
      ],
      "street" : "Morris Park Ave",
      "zipcode" : "10462"
   },
   "borough" : "Bronx",
   "cuisine" : "Bakery",
   "rating" : { "date" : ISODate("2014-03-03T00:00:00Z"),
                "grade" : "A",
                "score" : 2
              },
   "name" : "Morris Park Bake Shop",
   "restaurant_id" : "30075445"
}
```

You could add a partial index on the borough and cuisine fields choosing only to index documents where the **rating.grade** field is **A**:

```
db.restaurants.createIndex(
   { borough: 1, cuisine: 1 },
   { partialFilterExpression: { 'rating.grade': { $eq: "A" } } }
)
```

Hope this will help to you.